# Unable to locate the element as per the below anchor tag

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Please advise how to locate the link for New business tag in the below code. I have tried the following xpath but it didnt work:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("NEW BUSINESS")).click
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='hdBottomBar']/a[1]"))
```

HTML:

```
<span class="hdBottomBar">
                <a class="hdTopBar" href="javascript: void navCntl('NewBusiness','NavBar');" onmouseover="window.status='New Business';return true" onmouseout="window.status='';return true" name="newBusiness">NEW BUSINESS</a>
```

Comment: What does, "it didnt work", mean? Please post the relevant error messages, etc. Also add a tag for the language you want... Java?

Answer (score 1):

The element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so to invoke `click()` you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `linkText`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("NEW BUSINESS"))).click();
  ```
- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("span.hdBottomBar>a.hdTopBar[name='newBusiness']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class='hdBottomBar']/a[@class='hdTopBar' and @name='newBusiness'][text()='NEW BUSINESS']"))).click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
//span[@class='hdBottomBar']/a[@name='newBusiness']
```

or

```
//span[@class='hdBottomBar']/a[text()='NEW BUSINESS']
```